# compact metric spaces and infimum

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

I am currently revising metric spaces and have come across a question which I am unable to answer and have no idea how to begin with.

> Let $(M,d)$ be a compact metric space. Suppose $T \colon M \to M$ is a map such that for any $x,y \in M$ with $x \neq y$, $d(Tx,Ty) < d(x,y)$.
>
> 1. By considering the function $e(x) = d(x,Tx)$, $x \in M$ prove that $\inf\{d(x,Tx) : x \in M\}$ is attained
> 2. Prove that $\inf\{d(x,Tx) : x \in M\} = 0$.

I tried using contraction mappings but I'm not entirely sure if this can be applied here. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So let’s do as the question suggests and consider the function
$$
 e \colon M \to \mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto d(x,Tx).
$$
Notice that $e$ is continuous (even Lipschitz-continuous) because
\begin{align*}
 |e(x) - e(y)|
&= |d(x,Tx) - d(y,Ty)| \\
&\leq |d(x,Tx) - d(y,Tx)| + |d(y,Tx) - d(y,Ty)| \\
&\leq d(x,y) + d(Tx,Ty)
\leq d(x,y) + d(x,y)
= 2d(x,y).
\end{align*}
Because $M$ is compact it follows that $e$ attains its minimum on $M$, i.e. there exists some $x \in M$ with
$$
 d(x,T(x))
 = e(x)
 = \min_{y \in M} e(y)
 = \min \{d(y,Ty) \mid y \in M\}.
$$
That shows the first part. For the second part notice that if $x \neq Tx$ then
$$
d(Tx,T(Tx)) < d(x,Tx) = \min\{d(y,T(y)) \mid y \in M\},
$$
a contradiction. So we must have $x = Tx$ and thus
$$
 \min \{d(y,T(y)) \mid y \in M\} = d(x,Tx) = d(x,x) = 0.
$$

Comment: The map $T$ is clearly continuous (being Lipschitzian), so also $e$ is continuous as composition of continuous functions.

Comment: @egreg: This is certainly more elegant, but then you need to talk about metrizing the product $M \times M$ or topological products. This is why I chose this more low-level approach.

Comment: Yes, of course; I added it as a comment only for pointing out a simpler argument might be available. On the other hand, considerations about continuity of $d$ as a map $M\times M\to\mathbb{R}$ are often handy, because they avoid long chains of inequalities.